# Google Sheets App Scripts If Else doesn't work

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created the following app script in my google sheets but its returning always true. why is that?

```
  if (Dsheet.getRange('A3').isBlank) {
Logger.log('true');
var dest = Dsheet.getRange('A1')
source.copyTo (dest, {formatOnly: true});
source.copyTo (dest, {contentsOnly: true});
} else {
  Logger.log('false');
  var lastRow = Dsheet.getLastRow()+5;
  var dest = Dsheet.getRange('A' + lastRow )
  source.copyTo (dest, {formatOnly: true});
  source.copyTo (dest, {contentsOnly: true});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the function using `()`

```
 if (Dsheet.getRange('A3').isBlank())
```

Comment: omg i just missed ()